# DS4 Controller not working on Windows 10 after reset

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, game-controller

I reset my DS4 Controller to try to troubleshoot a completely unrelated issue, and now it won't connect to my PC. Neither wired nor wireless connection provides any input, even though the little "usb device has been connected" chime plays when plugging it in. When connecting with bluetooth, the controller connects perfectly fine, and says connected, but that's it. DS4Windows doesn't say there's any controllers connected, and although devices and printers lists it in the list, it seems like something's wrong as most of the fields are blank.

I have updated all the drivers related to the controller and restarted my pc. Please don't tell me to do those things, I'm asking a question here so I don't have the so-called "Windows Professionals" from the Windows 10 forums telling me to go to device manager and update the drivers 20 times.

[Screenshot of devices and printers screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq4pM.png)

Any tips are welcome as long as you don't tell me to update my drivers.

Comment: Assuming it was a hard reset, could the reset button be stuck? Does the Windows "Xbox Accessories" program see anything?

Comment: I won't post this as an answer yet as I'm not sure about the DS4, but if you have reset it then you will need to repeat the network setup on the DS4. So that it is compatible with your local network (DHCP on or off, IP address, DNS/gateway etc).